# Reference Request on Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not very good at linear algebra.My problem is that I don't find any motivation to study it.Can you suggest me a good book for Basic Linear Algebra??
I have gone through the Book by Friedberg and the book by Hoffman and Kunze.I know both book are good but I lack motivation.Can you suggest a good book to study linear algebra from basic.I won't mind if the book teaches me the Linear Algebra from the abstract point of view that is using the rings and all the stuff from basic Abstract Algebra!!

Comment: Sergei Treil - Linear Algebra Done Wrong
https://www.math.brown.edu/~treil/papers/LADW/LADW.html

Answer (score 3):

I like *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Axler because it keeps an abstract point of view and doesn't get convoluted with technicalities. The emphasis is on linear transformations and not matrices.